# Insert data into different tables in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, insert, sql-insert

Following is the original SP which always inserts into table1 (INSERT INTO table1). Now I need to insert either into table1 or table2 which both have the same structure.

I tried to pass the tableName as parameter into SP.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_importStats] (
@accountID BIGINT,  
@csvFileName VARCHAR (1024),
@csvFormatFileName VARCHAR (1024)
@tableName VARCHAR(256))
```

Then I tried to INSERT using EXECUTE as following:

```
--Incorrect syntax near EXECUTE.
EXECUTE(    
'INSERT INTO '+ @tableName + '(accountId, date, cost)
(SELECT cte.id, ms.date, ms.cost
FROM #stats ms
INNER JOIN CTE cte ON ms.accountNumber = cte.key4)');
```

Then I tried this:

```
--Must declare the table variable @tableName.
INSERT INTO @tableName (accountId, date, cost)
(SELECT cte.id, ms.date, ms.cost
FROM #stats ms
INNER JOIN CTE cte ON ms.accountNumber = cte.key4);
```

Then I tried not to pass the tableName and instead pass a boolean into SP and based on that decide which table I need to insert to:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_importStats] (
@accountID BIGINT,  
@csvFileName VARCHAR (1024),
@csvFormatFileName VARCHAR (1024),
@condition BIT = 0)

IF (@condition= 0)
SET @table = 'table1'
ELSE    
SET @table = 'table2'

--Must declare the table variable "@table".
INSERT INTO @table (accountId, date, cost)
(SELECT cte.id, ms.date, ms.cost
FROM #sats ms
INNER JOIN CTE cte ON ms.accountNumber = cte.key4);
```

I got error either way. Would you please let me know what's the best way to handle this? Why am I receiving these errors? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Original SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_importStats] (
@accountID BIGINT,  
@csvFileName VARCHAR (1024),
@csvFormatFileName VARCHAR (1024))

AS
BEGIN

CREATE TABLE #stats(
    [accountID]        [bigint]         NOT NULL,
    [accountNumber]    [varchar](30)        NULL,
    [date]             [datetime]       NOT NULL,       
    [cost]             [money]              NULL,       
);

EXECUTE('INSERT INTO #stats SELECT * FROM '+
    'OPENROWSET (BULK N''' + @csvFileName + '''' +      
    ',FORMATFILE='''+@csvFormatFileName+''''+
    ',FIRSTROW=2'+
    ',MAXERRORS=0'+
    ') AS t;');     

WITH CTE(id, key4) AS (
    SELECT  A.id, A.[key4]
    FROM    VA A (NOLOCK)
    WHERE   A.id = @accountID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  A.id, A.[key4]
    FROM    VA A (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN CTE ON (CTE.id = A.MAID)
    WHERE A.key4 IS NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO table1 (accountId, date, cost)
(SELECT cte.id, ms.date, ms.cost
FROM #stats ms
INNER JOIN CTE cte ON ms.accountNumber = cte.key4);

DROP TABLE #stats;

END
```

This is what I have now:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_importStats] (
@accountID BIGINT,  
@csvFileName VARCHAR (1024),
@csvFormatFileName VARCHAR (1024)
@tableName VARCHAR(256))

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

CREATE TABLE #stats(
    [accountID]        [bigint]         NOT NULL,
    [accountNumber]    [varchar](30)        NULL,
    [date]           [datetime]       NOT NULL,     
    [cost]             [money]              NULL,       
);

EXECUTE('INSERT INTO #stats SELECT * FROM '+
    'OPENROWSET (BULK N''' + @csvFileName + '''' +      
    ',FORMATFILE='''+@csvFormatFileName+''''+
    ',FIRSTROW=2'+
    ',MAXERRORS=0'+
    ') AS t;');     

WITH CTE(id, key4) AS (
    SELECT  A.id, A.[key4]
    FROM    VA A (NOLOCK)
    WHERE   A.id = @accountID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  A.id, A.[key4]
    FROM    VA A (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN CTE ON (CTE.id = A.MAID)
    WHERE A.key4 IS NOT NULL
)

--Incorect synstax near SET.
SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO '+ QUOTENAME(@tableName) + '(accountId, date, cost)
(SELECT cte.id, ms.date, ms.cost
FROM #stats ms
INNER JOIN CTE cte ON ms.accountNumber = cte.key4)';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;

DROP TABLE #stats;

END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Passing Table Name as Parameter**

Use `QUOTENAME() Function` to put square brackets around your table names to tell sql server explicitly that it is a Sql Server Object name something like this ..

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

 SET @Sql = N';WITH CTE(id, key4) AS (
                SELECT  A.id, A.[key4]
                FROM    VA A (NOLOCK)
                WHERE   A.id = @accountID
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  A.id, A.[key4]
                FROM    VA A (NOLOCK)
                INNER JOIN CTE ON (CTE.id = A.MAID)
                WHERE A.key4 IS NOT NULL
            )
            INSERT INTO ' +  QUOTENAME(@tableName) +' (accountId, date, cost)
            SELECT cte.id, ms.date, ms.cost
            FROM #stats ms
            INNER JOIN CTE cte ON ms.accountNumber = cte.key4;'  

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
```

Using QUOTENAME() Function can protect you against a possible `sql injection attack`. Also you do not need parenthesis around your select statement.

Also you should avoid using `sp_` prefix for you stored Procedure names. [Read Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172115%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) why.

**Using IF..ELSE Blocks**

```
IF (Some_Condition IS TRUE)
 BEGIN
   /* Insert Statement For Table One*/  --<-- No need to use table Names as variable
 END                                       -- just hardcode the table names in your
ELSE                                       -- Insert Statements
 BEGIN
   /* Insert Statement For Table Two*/
 END
```

Comment: I get: Incorect synstax near SET. Is this b/c I have CTE defined before that?

Comment: @blueSky update your question show exactly what you are doing ??

Comment: Updated my post with SP with what you suggested.

Comment: I also get "Incorrect syntax near 'IF'" if try the 2nd solution.

Comment: @blueSky sorry I didnt realise you were inserting values from your CTE, this CTE needs to go in your dynamic sql statement, Have a look I have update my answer

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Few questions: 1) Why do you have: @Sql = N'? Is N a typo? 2) Can I still use the IF/ELSE as well as 2nd solution?

Comment: @blueSky prefixing your strings with `N` means you are telling sql server that there can be some unicode characters in the following string. yes you can also use `IF..ELSE` block, IF..ELSE blocks will give you a lot more lines of code in your proc where as dynamic sql builds the query dynamically for you. Personally I would avoid using dynamic sql whenever possible.

Comment: I would like to use IF/ELSE as well but then I get "Incorrect syntax near 'IF'". Would you please tell me how can I use IF/ELSE with CTE?

Comment: Already accepted the answer. Just would like to know the IF/ELSE too if possible.

Comment: Yes absolutely but then you will have to write the whole insert statement in both IF and ELSE blocks, you will end up with more lines of code but it does the same job. I mean if you dont want people to pass a table name as a parameter then if..else blocks is the only way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice that you missed a comma in declaration.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_importStats] (
@accountID BIGINT,  
@csvFileName VARCHAR (1024),
@csvFormatFileName VARCHAR (1024),---comma missing here
@tableName VARCHAR(256))
```